# How to embed an if statement into php footer

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

I'm completely new to PHP, so please bear with me.

I have a WP website, that I have not created (I barely understand PHP), but I have been tasked with putting an if statement into the footer.php

The idea is to have an if statement that will check which page is loaded, and then provide appropriate `<a href="...">` in the footer.
So, if the index.php is loaded `<a href="...">` in the footer should lead to website X. If ANY other page is loaded then the `<a href="...">` in the footer should lead to website Y.

In other words - I want the footer link to lead to website X only when the user is viewing the index.php, if any other page is loaded I want it to lead the user to website Y.

Would anyone be able to give me an example of how to achieve this? I have tried googling and I understand the solution is there, but being new to PHP I've had no luck.

Comment: Take a look at the is_page() WordPress function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ and use this in your php if statement https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP function `is_front_page()` for that. It checks if you are on the frontpage of the website. For more info, see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/

`is_home()` is very similar, BTW: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

In both cases I would recommend to use a child theme, since your code modifications will be lost when the used theme is updated: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wp_footer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) hook. Also from [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to recognize the home screen.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ywp_show_link_in_footer' );
function ywp_show_link_in_footer() {
    if( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        echo '<a href="http://www.x.com/"';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="http://www.y.com/"';
    }
}
```